# Logout user when tab or browser closed but should not logout when browser refreshes in React Js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to logout my application when tab or browser closed but not when it refreshes. I tried EventListeners "beforeunload" and "unload" to apply logout function but same function calling when page refresh and even if we click on anchor links. how to differentiate both refresh and tab close events.
I will post code which I tried.
here I am trying to clear store data to get app logout

```
useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('beforeunload', alertUser)
    window.addEventListener('unload', handleTabClosing)
    return () => {
        window.removeEventListener('beforeunload', alertUser)
        window.removeEventListener('unload', handleTabClosing)
              
    }
        
})
    
const handleTabClosing = async(e) => {
    await localStorage.clear();
        
}
    
const alertUser = (event:any) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    event.returnValue = '
```

Comment: If you just want to logout on tab or browser close but not on refresh you can just set the toggle in sessionStorage, it works very similar to localStorage but expires on tab or browser close and survives page reloads

Comment: @thenaamsake This is an answer rather than a comment. Would you like to post this as an answer?

Comment: can you please just add code how it would toggle . thanks in advance